# Newbie trying to animate object on mouse click. Using OnMouseDown()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a 3D object, broken into 5 parts. When a user clicks on the object, it opens and shows internals. This works fine using OnMouseDown(). What I'm trying to do is make these objects slowly move when clicked, as opposed to just jumping to the finish point. Below is the code. What am I doing wrong here? I haven't really worked on cleaning up the code as I'm trying to just get the functionality to work.

I've uploaded the code to GitHub as well so you can see all the scripts that are in the project.

[GothardJ2/BatteryBreakdown: Code for the battery breakdown](https://github.com/GothardJ2/BatteryBreakdown) (github.com)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class OpenBattery : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField] float moveSpeed = .05f;
    [SerializeField] GameObject top;
    [SerializeField] GameObject board;
    [SerializeField] GameObject cells;
    [SerializeField] GameObject bottom;

    public bool isOpen = false;
    public ExtendCells extendCells;

    void Start()
    {

    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    void OnMouseDown()
    
    {
        if (isOpen == false)
        {
            OpenBatteryCase();
        }

        else if (isOpen && extendCells.isExtended == false)
        {
            CloseBatteryCase();
        }
    }

    private void CloseBatteryCase()
    {
        Vector3 topXMovement = new Vector3(-0.99f, 0f, 0f);
        Vector3 boardXMovement = new Vector3(-0.68f, 0f, 0f);
        Vector3 bottomXMovement = new Vector3(0.79f, 0f, 0f);

        top.transform.Translate(topXMovement);
        board.transform.Translate(boardXMovement);
        bottom.transform.Translate(bottomXMovement);
        isOpen = false;
    }

    private void OpenBatteryCase()
    {
        Debug.Log("Close");
        Vector3 topXMovement = new Vector3(0.99f, 0f, 0f);
        Vector3 boardXMovement = new Vector3(0.68f, 0f, 0f);
        Vector3 bottomXMovement = new Vector3(-0.79f, 0f, 0f);

        top.transform.Translate(topXMovement * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        board.transform.Translate(boardXMovement);
        bottom.transform.Translate(bottomXMovement);
        isOpen = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a concept of Coroutines in Unity for making things like these. Coroutines are different than void methods. It's simply a way to make waits or move object in time etc.

```
public IEnumerator enumerator()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x+1, transform.position.y,transform.position.z);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        }
    }
```

For example in the above code, transform's position is changing with the intervals of 0.1 seconds in every for loop is looping.
And to start this Coroutine you can't just simply use

```
enumerator();
```

instead it starts like this:

```
StartCoroutine(enumerator());
```

Just don't use a Coroutine inside the Update method. It's a beginner error.

And to stop it:

```
StopAllCoroutines();
```

This stops not just this Coroutine, but all working Coroutines.

For further information on Coroutines check this:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html